# Unable to invoke multiple batch files

Tags: batch-file

I have VBScript file as follows which launches multiple batch files.

### Invoke.vbs

```
const RunbatchtLocation = "C:\Temp"
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
shell.run RunbatchtLocation & "\Launch.bat",1,True
```

### Launch.bat

```
start cmd /k "C:\Temp\All10.bat"
start cmd /k "C:\Temp\30.bat"
C:\Temp\50.bat
```

The above file able will executed All10.bat , 30.bat and 50.bat which is work fine.

My problem is here in All10.bat which is as follows:

```
CALL "c:\temp\10-1.bat"
CALL "c:\temp\10-2.bat"
CALL "c:\temp\10-3.bat"
```

It starts with 10-1.bat and is able to execute all the specified files, but after it completes it stops and never executes 10-2.bat or 10-3.bat.

Will someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Show us the content of 10-1.bat. Does it invoke another bat without call? Does it invoke exit?

Comment: The content of 10-1 is as follows and it is same for 10-2 and 10-3  and has a call to exit
timeout /t 10
REM `@echo. > C:\temp\File10-1.bat
timeout /t 5
exit

I tried removing the exit call but no luck the execution details is as follows

C:\1033>"c:\temp\10-1.bat"

C:\1033>timeout /t 10

Waiting for  0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

C:\1033>REM `@echo. > C:\temp\File10-1.bat

C:\1033>timeout /t 5

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
C:\1033>

Comment: It erases itself?

Comment: I did not get this point ?

 
**It erases itself?**

Comment: I might be missing something because the way the code is formatted in a comment. Please post it in your question instead.

Comment: you are echoing an empty string to the same file10-1.bat, arent you?

Comment: That line is a comment . But if i will un-comment it will create a file called File10-1 . only thing is the file extension should be .txt instead of .bat